# How to enlarge an image only in upward side out of its container width provided when its hover on it?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to create a page in which if user **hover** over any image which are inside a wrapper div the image would enlarge slightly upward out of wrapper div but with my code the image is only increasing its width and it remains inside the ***wrapper*** div only for eg :

```css
.Wrap {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.Wrap ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
.Wrap ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.Wrap ul li:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
.Images {
  width: 100px;
  transition: width 0.8s ease, height 0.8s ease;
}
.Wrap ul li:hover .Images {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Wrap">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/bj57qwh8z/vlcsnap_error262.png" class="Images" alt="" id="#img1">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/bj57qwh8z/vlcsnap_error262.png" class="Images" alt="" id="#img2">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/bj57qwh8z/vlcsnap_error262.png" class="Images" alt="" id="#img3">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

I also tried to make the image **position relative** and move it from ***bottom*** but in that case only the image is move upward and the background is still inside the **wrapper** div only for eg:

```css
.Wrap {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.Wrap ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
.Wrap ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.Wrap ul li:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
.Images {
  width: 100px;
  transition: width 0.8s ease, height 0.8s ease;
}
.Wrap ul li:hover .Images {
  width: 300px;
  position:relative;
  bottom:100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Wrap">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/bj57qwh8z/vlcsnap_error262.png" class="Images" alt="" id="#img1">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/bj57qwh8z/vlcsnap_error262.png" class="Images" alt="" id="#img2">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/bj57qwh8z/vlcsnap_error262.png" class="Images" alt="" id="#img3">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

My requirement for output is such that the image should increase its width and should enlarge just about 40 to 50 px above its **wrapper div** along with its background being intact with it.

Comment: Your wrapper does not have a set height, so CSS assumes it to be fluid. It will always increase height to accommodate the elements within, unless you supply it with a height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you listed CSS3, I've tried to do the transition with `scale()` and `translate3d()` rather than `width` and `height`. Is this more what you were looking to achieve? You can play with the scale and translate values on the `<li>` and `<img>` to your liking.

You'll also need to add the proper CSS to make it cross-browser.

```css
.Wrap {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.Wrap ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
.Wrap ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  transform: scale(1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.8s ease;
}
.Wrap ul li:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: scale(1.8) translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
}

.Images {
  width: 100px;
  /* transition: width 0.8s ease, height 0.8s ease; */
}
.Wrap ul li:hover .Images {
/*
  width: 300px;
  position:relative;
  bottom:100px;
  transform: scale(2);
*/
}
```

```html
  <div class="Wrap">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/bj57qwh8z/vlcsnap_error262.png" class="Images" alt="" id="#img1">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/bj57qwh8z/vlcsnap_error262.png" class="Images" alt="" id="#img2">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/bj57qwh8z/vlcsnap_error262.png" class="Images" alt="" id="#img3">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help mate :) !